# Is there way to enable "Step into selection" for C++ in Eclipse?

Tags: c++, eclipse, debugging

There is very convenient "Step into specific" functionality in Visual Studio C++ on Windows. I have heard that a similar functionality "Step into selection" can be found for Java in Eclipse. Is there something similar for Eclipse CDT (C++) on Ubuntu?

Comment: From my experience I have learned that the need for this functionality to skip copy constructors hints for a problem in the code. One should use pass-by-reference-to-const rather than pass-by-copy unless the latter is really needed. This, however, doesn't solve the problem with overloaded arrow operator, which is commonly seen in smart pointers.

Comment: erm... I think you responded to the wrong post

Comment: Yeah... the comment was too twisted. To put it in other words, if one badly needs "step into specific" to skip many copy constructors, then it suggests a problem in the code. Passing by reference to const allows to avoid copying.

Comment: oh, you are saying the code you are trying to step through is bad, rather then making a comment on the source code of eclipse?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I am not so sure what you mean by 'step into selection', but I can tell you that Eclipse IDE (I use it for Java, but believe it offers the same functionality for C++) lets your perform the following during debug

- Step over, so line by line. Note however that if you have a function call within a function call, this will count as to 'lines', so you step through twice, as you would expect
- Step out of. Executes the rest of this block, usually resulting in executing the rest of the function
- Step into. This is what I think you are on about, this will enter into a function call so you can step through the individual lines of that function
- Run to selection. This lets you have the program execute as normal and stop again at where your cursor is (This one can be accessed via the right click menu)

I hope I have understood what you are asking for, leave a comment if you need me to explain anything better.

Based on the extra information from the OP, I believe the answer is no. Eclipse does not support this functionality in the debugger

There is functionality to navigate the code base, 'F3' is by default used to jump to the implementation of a function. Again, I am talking about Eclipse for Java here. Not sure if it works during debug, but you could use it to navigate to the source of the function in question, then right click and select 'run to here'. Whilst admittedly not as nice as it sounds like VS does it, it may just be the best option. Assuming it actually works that is

Comment: 'Step into selection' means doing a 'step into' in a line with various methods, for example: doSomething(doInnerMethod(5)); In this case, if you want to step into the 'doSomething()', you can specify it specifically and the debugger will skip the 'doInnerMethod()', which avoids many: "F5 (step into) -> is this the method I'm interested? If not -> F7"

Comment: Ah, now that I do not know, but I don't think it is able to do that

Comment: Exactly. The idea is to skip a bazillion of overloaded dereference operators and copy constructors and go strait to the function of interest.

Comment: This is a best answer, but I grant 100 points to Edison since he was the first person to answer.

Comment: Well, I am not going to complain to much, simply point out that 12:26 comes a full ten minutes before 12:36

Comment: @Sergiy: Contrary to popular belief, Stackoverflow is _not_ about being _The Fastest Gun in the West™_, but about providing the _most accurate_ and _most helpful_ answer.

Answer (score 4):

No, it's not implemented at the eclipse IDE debugger.

Comment: Can you please point a source of this information? Point to a relevant source code will work too. Thank you.

Comment: ¬_¬ how can he point to the relevant source code for a feature that does not exist? You think there is going to be some sort note "hey guys, we could add this kick ass feature, but lets not"

Comment: For instance, one can point to the code that implements the feature for Java and then show that similar function is not implemented for C++. Also it was just a suggestion. Edison's answer suggests that he knows for sure - I wonder where did he get this information from.

Comment: It's not implemented in java nor in CDT